# laravel doesn't upload file

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this in view.blade.php

```
{!!Form::open(['url'=>'/Path/somepath','method'=>'POST','files'=>true])!!}
<div>
    <span>{!!Form::label('Photo','Your photo')!!}</span>
     <span>{!! Form::file('Photo')!!}</span>
</div>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

I have this in the controller method:

```
    $destinationPath = 'Folder/Subfolder1/Subfolder2'; 
    $extension = Input::file('Photo')->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    $size = Input::file('Photo')->getSize();
    $mime = Input::file('Photo')->getMimeType();
    $path = Input::file('Photo')->getRealPath();
    $fileName=’ 3da0d12d6d8667963392a446262b1773JJ.jpg’;
    $ufile=Input::file('Photo');
    $ufile->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    $details=[$size,$mime,$path,$fileName,$ufile];
    dd($details);
```

and the result is this:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => 7673
  1 => "image/jpeg"
  2 => "C:\wamp2\tmp\php984F.tmp"
  3 => "3da0d12d6d8667963392a446262b1773JJ.jpg"
  4 => UploadedFile {#29 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "vali.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 7673
    -error: 0
  }
]
```

But when I look into `C:\wamp2\tmp\` the  file `php984F.tmp` is not there. My problem was that moving the file to another path was not working… it can’t be working since the uploading seems not to work in the first place. 
So, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The result looks fine, check that there is valid directory `Folder/Subfolder1/Subfolder2` and has `777` permission

Comment: How do I check that ?  And why there is no file in C:\wamp2\tmp ?

Comment: it's a temporary file, it will be deleted after transfer

Answer (score 1):

correct the destination directory path

```
 $destinationPath = base_path() . '/Folder/Subfolder1/Subfolder2'; // replace with your required destination directory
```